# MSXML removes the encoding="UTF-8" attribute

Tags: c++, xml, encoding, utf-8, msxml

I'm reading the following XML text from a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SampleXML>...</SampleXML>
```

and I load the UTF-8 text using IXMLDomDocument::loadXML. Then I manipulate the XML and call IXMLDomDocument::Getxml() to get a _bstr_t of the modified XML. this _bstr_t looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ModifiedSampleXML>...</ModifiedSampleXML>
```

The encoding="UTF-8" attribute in the header is gone. However, if I call IXMLDomDocument::save(FileName) to save the XML to a file, when I open the file I see that the encoding="UTF-8" attribute is preserved.

Why the encoding="UTF-8" attribute is not there when I call Getxml()? How do I tell MSXML to always preserve this attribute? (not only upon save)

Comment: It might not really be an issue. If encoding is not specified, your XML file is assumed to be in UTF-8 by default.

Comment: If you get the xml text using method Getxml() you will get a UTF-16 string since strings in windows are always UTF-16 encoded. Therefor to be consistent Getxml() removes all encoding instructions other than encoding="UTF-16". But if you save(..) the xml to a file then your encoding instruction will show up. You can even use encoding="ISO-8859-1" - it will then be saved properly with this encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute "encoding='UTF-8'" is removed because `Getxml()` returns the loaded XML in wide character (16-bit) string.
You can verify this by looking into the memory held by the returned `_bstr_t`.

It would be incorrect for MSXML to preserve the attribute that says the encoding is 8-bits when in fact it is 16-bits.

If however you load a unicode xml file having "encoding='UTF-16'" attribute, you will see that `Getxml()` will not remove the attribute.